# Can VS launch FireFox in a new window when hitting F5?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, firefox, web-applications, browser

I am using FireFox as my default browser. I am using the setting "Open new windows in a new tab instead", since this is what I prefer when just browsing the web. However, this means that when I hit F5 in VS to start debugging, the web app is opened in a new tab in the active FireFox instance, alongside any other tabs I have opened already. I would like to separate my debugging sessions from my normal browsing so that VS always opens a new browser window when debugging, but at the same time keep my normal browser preferences for regular browsing. Is it possible somehow to tweak the way VS opens the browser when I hit F5?

I have already tried the "Start external program" option in VS, with command line arguments to open FF in a new window. The problem is that VS does not attach to the process, which makes it pretty useless.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a WebForm file in VS (anything ending in .aspx  will do)
2. Select the "Browse With..." option from the File menu
3. Select your preferred browser from the list and click the "Set as Default" button

Comment: source: http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2007/08/02/setting-a-default-browser-for-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking to just set the default browser. My default browser for debugging *is* firefox just like I want it to be. I am looking for a way to customize the way firefox is launched from within VS.